# My android app with externalProject_add (cmake) dont execute ninja

Tags: android, flutter, cmake, build.gradle, ninja

I'm creating a flutter plugin that uses cmake to build an external library. It turns out that when I run the app, it creates all the dependencies (build.ninja, build_output, build_command, etc.) for the proper architectures, but does not run the ninja to copy and build the directory of the external library.

My build.gradle:

```
group 'com.example.cmake'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

rootProject.allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
      path "CMakeLists.txt"
      version "3.17.2"
    }
  }
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

My CmakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17.0)
project(mupdf)

include(ExternalProject)
find_program(MAKE_EXE NAMES gmake nmake make)

ExternalProject_Add(mupdf
  URL ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/mupdf
  LOG_DOWNLOAD true
  CONFIGURE_COMMAND ""
  BUILD_IN_SOURCE true
  BUILD_COMMAND ${MAKE_EXE} USE_SYSTEM_LIBS=no HAVE_X11=no HAVE_GLUT=no shared=yes build/shared-release/libsample.so
  LOG_BUILD true
  INSTALL_COMMAND ""
)
```

Build_command.txt, that is created from the gradle:

```
Executable : /usr/local/bin/cmake
arguments : 
-H/home/marco/Documentos/Projetos/sadapp/assinador/android
-B/home/marco/Documentos/Projetos/sadapp/assinador/android/.cxx/cmake/debug/x86
-DANDROID_ABI=x86
-DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-16
-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=/home/marco/Documentos/Projetos/sadapp/assinador/example/build/assinador/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/x86
-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug
-DANDROID_NDK=/home/marco/Android/Sdk/ndk/21.1.6352462
-DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=Android
-DCMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI=x86
-DCMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION=16
-DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON
-DCMAKE_ANDROID_NDK=/home/marco/Android/Sdk/ndk/21.1.6352462
-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/home/marco/Android/Sdk/ndk/21.1.6352462/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake
-G Ninja
jvmArgs :
```